# Image Slideshow with audio

Tags: android, image, audio, slideshow

I have a requirement that I want to play an audio  file and meanwhile I should get slideshow of images stored in array.

Can any one suggest me the way to do this?

Thanks in Advance,

Tejaswi Marakini

Answer (score 0):

you could have a class called Slide that extends view, inside the Slide class could be the drawable image and the playable audiofile. Then in your main class you could change the slides and put in a delay or whatnot.